# Celery only one physical server

Tags: celery, celery-task

Details:
We have multiple jobs runnig in crontab.
Those jobs call a set a apis say 10 and do some calculation and send reports.
Some times same cron job calls the same api again.
My task is i need to move this to celery.
Problem is there is only one physical server.
I have done similar things but we had multiple physical servers.So i knew to which server i was offloading the
cpu/gpu bound task.
Here there is only one physical server.physical cpu count is 4.
Will it be worth the effort and show some actual improvement if i move all this to celery ?

this is still being analyzed